# I'm using @react-native-firebase and I'm trying to build my iOS app but getting this error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-firebase

Here's the full context of the error:
`Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects` Podfile`and have run`pod install`.

See http://invertase.link/ios for the ios setup guide.`

my PodFile:

```
# Created by react-native-pod
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'myapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

my package.json contains this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@callstack/reanimated-arc": "^0.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.3",
```

I kept on seeing that RNFirebase is found in `react-native-firebase` package but i already have `@react-native-firebase`

My Libraries folder in XCode is also empty and i already did `npx react-native link @react-native-firebase/app`

How do i remove the error and build the app properly

**UPDATE:**
When i do `react-native run-ios`, it works. But when I run on XCode, it does not. Any info on this please

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it appears that the react-native link was not working properly in my case, so make sure that on Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries you add libRNFirebase.a if it is not there, which it might not be. I will just leave it here in case someone comes and is still having trouble with it. Make sure that you have added $(inherited) both for debug and release with a recursive value.

Comment: Hi! I cannot find libRNFirebase.a file as well. How do i find it? Also, what do you mean for $(inherited)

Comment: Heyy. 
1) open xcode under  build phases  If you search for Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries, check if all project libraries are there; if not, click on the plus button, then RNFirebase.a file, add it, then restart the app with clear build folder and clear issues.

2 ) $(inherited) assigns inherited values for Platform Defaults , Xcode Project xcconfig File , Xcode Project File Build Settings

Comment: I dont have an RNFirebase.a file anywhere. Where do i get it from?